# Get quota usage information as non-privileged user

Tags: linux, cgroups, quota

I have non-privileged access to a Linux server (shared PHP+MySQL hosting) and there are disk space, memory, CPU usage, I/O quotas.

I wonder how can I get information about max/current quota usage from SSH shell?

Comment: Depends entirely on how these quotas are enforced, there are multiple solutions for this out there. You could try to find out what the provider uses and then proceed to find out. **Or you could just ask them**.

Comment: The answer was "use `du -s`"

Comment: The answer to what? This post?

Comment: Putting a bounty on this question won't help much if you don't tell us how quotas are enforced...

Comment: I believe it's cgroups

Comment: Check if you have *read* access to [`/etc/cgconfig.conf`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cgroups#Persistent_group_configuration) file and `/etc/cgconfig.d/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

**Granting Access to Specific Files as Another User**

The `sudo -u` entry allows allows you to execute a command as if you were another user, but first you have to be granted this privilege in the `sudoers` file.
This feature can be convenient for programmers who sometimes need to kill processes related to projects they are working on. For example, programmer peter is on the team developing a financial package that runs a program called `monthend` as user accounts. From time to time the application fails, requiring "peter" to stop it with the `/bin/kill`, `/usr/bin/kill` or `/usr/bin/pkill` commands but only as user "accounts". The `sudoers` entry would look like this:

```
peter ALL=(accounts) /bin/kill, /usr/bin/kill, /usr/bin/pkill
```

User `peter` is allowed to stop the `monthend` process with this command:

```
[peter@bigboy peter]# sudo -u accounts pkill monthend
```